# Powershell if with -OR operator

Tags: powershell

Is the following syntax correct because the code is not skipping as it should.

```
foreach($acc in get-SPmanagedAccount)
{
    $accNamewithDomain = $acc.UserName
    $accname = $accNamewithDomain.Split("\")[1] 

    if(($accName -ne "svc-reader-tst") -or ($accName -ne "svc-writer-tst"))
    {
       # do somthing
    }
}
```

Comment: `x != "foo" || x != "bar"` will always be true. You want `-and`

Comment: @Arnavion: Thanks. -and operator did the job. I appreciated it.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question so that it no longer makes sense and isn't valuable to future readers.  If Arnavion doesn't want to post an answer, you should post your own and accept it.

Comment: @BaconBits: Thanks for the advice. I have updated the original post with -or operator and posted the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code with -and operator per Arnavion and it's working as expected.

```
foreach($acc in get-SPmanagedAccount)
{
    $accNamewithDomain = $acc.UserName
    $accname = $accNamewithDomain.Split("\")[1] 

    if(($accName -ne "svc-reader-tst") -and ($accName -ne "svc-writer-tst"))
    {
       # do somthing
    }
}
```